# Calculating the sub total from a list of check boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello I have written the following codes to handle the selection of check boxes in a form. the grand total should be incremented based on the slections and then displayed. Would someone please help me on how to ago about with this. Here is how I am processing the selections and trying to calculate the grand total.

```
    Private Sub computeCurrentSelection()
    If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        total = ugalif * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If

    If chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
        orderAmt = lab3.Text
        total = ugalid * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkUgaliB.Checked = True Then 'githeri selected
        orderAmt = lab2.Text
        total = githeri * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Githeri " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkPilau.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab4.Text
        total = chapo * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pilau " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkPizza.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab5.Text
        total = pilau * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pizza " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkMandazi.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab6.Text
        total = pizza * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "mandazi " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSamosa.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab7.Text
        total = mandazi * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Samosa " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkChapon.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab8.Text
        total = samosa * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Chapati " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkWater.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water1 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkWater.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water2 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water3 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkWater.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water4 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda1 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda2 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda3 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda4 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice1 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice2 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice3 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice4 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The total should be calculated from an individual checkbox items i.e ` If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
 orderAmt = lab.Text
 total = ugalif * orderAmt
 subtotal = total
 lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & " Kshs" & total)
        End If ` but the subtotal should be the sum of the totals of all the selected check boxes i.e if only one checkbox is selected then the subtotal should be only the total of the checkbox but if more than one is selected then the subtotal should be the sum of the totals from all the selected check boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but I will give it a go.

Try this:

```
Private Function ComputeCurrentSelection() As Integer ' not sure for data type, you decide
    Dim total As Integer
    If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        total += ugalif * orderAmt        
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If

    If chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
        orderAmt = lab3.Text
        total += ugalid * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkUgaliB.Checked = True Then 'githeri selected
        orderAmt = lab2.Text
        total += githeri * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Githeri " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If ...

    Return total
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

```
      Private Sub computeCurrentSelection()
    If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        total = ugalif * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If

    If chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
        orderAmt = lab3.Text
        total = ugalid * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkUgaliB.Checked = True Then 'githeri selected
        orderAmt = lab2.Text
        total = githeri * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Githeri " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkPilau.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab4.Text
        total = chapo * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pilau " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkPizza.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab5.Text
        total = pilau * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pizza " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkMandazi.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab6.Text
        total = pizza * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "mandazi " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSamosa.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab7.Text
        total = mandazi * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Samosa " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkChapon.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab8.Text
        total = samosa * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Chapati " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkWater.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water1 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkWater.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water2 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water3 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkWater.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water4 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l Water " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda1 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda2 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda3 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkSoda.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total += soda4 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l Soda " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice1 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice2 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice3 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
    If chkJuice.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice4 * orderAmt
        subtotal += total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l juice " & " Kshs" & total)
    End If
End Sub
```

and it has worked but it computes and stores the subtotal thus updating it wherever I call computeCurrentSelection(), for example if on the first call the subtotal was 10, try clearing the previous total and updating it like this

```
    Private Sub updateTotal()
    lstTotal.Items.Clear()
    lstTotal.Items.Add("Sub Total =" & subtotal)
End Sub
```

the clearing does not work but instead keeps on incrementing the current value of the sub total by the previous one until I refresh the program. 
How can I solve that?